# How to hook a function into filter in a class of plugin from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, object

I am not very old on Wordpress.

I am developing a website which has a Third party plugin having class `Plugin_Class` and there are some filters in the construct of it. I want to hook my additional function to filter `Plugin_filter_1` from functions.php.

I have tried with the syntax `add_filter( 'Plugin_filter_1', array('Plugin_Class', 'my_function_defined_in_functions_php' ) );`,

it gives me error even if the class is visible ( `checked with get_declared_classes()` )

The detailed answer will be appreciated

Thanks for your help
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the issue is that your second parameter for `add_filter` is an array with `Plugin_Class` as the first element- this means wordpress will try to fire `PluginClass::my_function_defined_in_functions_php`, which doesn't exist.

Instead, just pass it a string of `'my_function_defined_in_functions_php'`.

If this doesn't work with just this edit, show us the code in the plugin class- including the class name and entire construct method. There are more possible issues.